# unable to sign in with account created using MS graph API

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

i have created an AZURE AD user(Local Account) using MS Graph API with following attributes

```
            AccountEnabled = true,
            DisplayName = "Adele Vance",
            MailNickname = "AdeleV",                 ,
            UserPrincipalName = "abc@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
            passwordProfile = new PasswordProfile
            {
                forceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true,
                password = "Okkaework1"
            }
            passwordPolicies = "DisablePasswordExpiration"
```

user(Local Account) is created successfully, and can be seen in "Users" in user portal.
but when i sign in first time with this account it gives me the error:
The message is: **The username or password provided in the request are invalid.**
then i made a change in TrustFrameworkbase file as removing `<Item Key="grant_type">password</Item> from <TechnicalProfile Id="login-NonInteractive">`[following this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/178990/azure-b2c-custom-policies-error-message.html)

then tried to sign in again now i am facing the error **"The password has expired"**
i am stuck at this step as i can not log in with this newly created user and dont know hoew to get success in signing in.
any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: I followed this tutorial to create a user, and I can use the newly created account to sign in azure portal. Could you pls share the app which you signed failed?

Comment: forceChangePasswordNextSignIn set this to false. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51395601/4164473

Comment: @saravana i havr tried this also forceChangePasseordNextSignin=false but same error

Comment: @tiny i tried to sign in through azura portal-sign sign up policy test-run now and reply url at jwt.ms and my asp.net core web application(regestered to AAD B2C) both givinh same error

Comment: Can you please tell are my attributes correct which set to create a user. And for sign in i give that UPN in email and that passward which i set for user creation shoen above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the method you are using will create a work account rather than a consumer account. See the differences between work account and consumer account [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-overview).

To create a local account, you should follow this example: [Create a user with social and local account identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-create-a-user-with-social-and-local-account-identities), by specifying the `identities/issuer` as "contoso.onmicrosoft.com" (your tenant domain). Reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/objectidentity?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) (See **issuer**).

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users
Content-type: application/json

{
  "displayName": "John Smith",
  "identities": [
    {
      "signInType": "userName",
      "issuer": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
      "issuerAssignedId": "johnsmith"
    },
    {
      "signInType": "emailAddress",
      "issuer": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
      "issuerAssignedId": "jsmith@yahoo.com"
    }
  ],
  "passwordProfile" : {
    "password": "password-value",
    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": false
  },
  "passwordPolicies": "DisablePasswordExpiration"
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,yes i have already made these changes...and its working,can you please tell me further how can i set consumer account UPN (UseraPrincipalName) while creating that user

Comment: @MunazzaOsama I'm afraid that you need to [update the user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).